# does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface

Tags: java, spring

Iam getting the error below:- 

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:128) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]`

I checked the lib folder, it spring-beans-3.2, spring-tx & spring-context-3.2 jar files. I used the below namespaces:-
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd.

Classpath has the required jars files.

Please help in troubleshooting the error.

WIndows 7

Comment: Let me guess deploying to an application server like WebLogic?

Comment: I am not sure could be possible your spring-context dependencies not matched. If possible add you pom.xml in your question or add complete stacktrace

Comment: @M.Deinum yes it is happening on weblogic 12cR2 any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try this `xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"` and `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       https://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd`. If you are getting the same then please remove version **-3.2** from context and beans.

Comment: Changing the xsd declaration won't help solving this.